# usage of " SapGuiLibrary.Doubleclick Element " in robot framework using Python

Tags: robotframework, sap-gui

I am trying to double click in an object in a table falling under a shell in sapwingui (for test automation) using robot framework sapgui library with Python,
and i am trying to use the function SapGuiLibrary.Doubleclick .
The function has three arguments :
element_id, item_id, column_id
Can someone please let me know what exactly is difference between element and item id here.